# Has any goalkeeper ever received a red card at the FIFA World cup?

Tags: football, officiating, trivia, history, world-cup

I heard that in football, the referee can give red cards even to goalkeepers.

Are there any goalkeepers who have received a red card in FIFA World Cup matches?

If yes, please provide the details.

Comment: This year? Or ever? It's uncommon, but happens regularly enough that giving an exhaustive list is likely impractical.

Comment: @waxeagle, removed yellow cards. Isn't it possible to list out the goal keepers who received red cards in the whole FIFA world cups?

Comment: that would be a much smaller list I'm sure. The total number of reds is <200 for the whole history of the tournament

Comment: One that perhaps should have been is Harald Schumacher, now this was a proper foul...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPTOnClKCJc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three goalkeepers that have been sent off in World Cup matches:

- The first goalkeeper to be sent off in a World Cup match was the Italian keeper [Gianluca Pagliuca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gianluca_Pagliuca) in [1994 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_E). He was given a straight red card for handling the ball outside the box.
- The second was [Itumeleng Khune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itumeleng_Khune), a South African keeper who was sent off during a match against Uruguay during the [2010 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A), after tripping an opponent in the box.
- The third was [Wayne Hennessey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayne_Hennessey) of Wales, who was sent off in a match against Iran at the [2022 FIFA World Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_B), after colliding with an opponent.

The complete history of red cards at the World Cup can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FIFA_World_Cup_red_cards).